# Best way to get a list of countries in Java

Tags: java

Other than `Locale.getISOCountries()` that is, because I'm already [getting some strange errors with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712230/weird-error-with-locale-getisocountries). What else is the best way to get the 2-letter country codes as well as the full country name?

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace over here? And jdk you are using? Or try without importing java.util.Locale.getISOCountries(), just to be sure its same Locale you intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a separate project, I took the country code data from the [ISO site](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm).

Beware of the following:

- The names are in all caps.  You will probably want to tweak it so it's not.
- The names are not all in simple ASCII.
- The names are not entirely political neutral (it is probably impossible for any purported list of countries to be).  E.g., "Taiwan, Province of China" is a name.  A good starting point to learn about the issues is [this blog post](http://www.koziarski.net/archives/2008/9/24/countries-and-controversies).

Comment: The ISO link is now broken.

Comment: ...and the blog post link now triggers huge security warnings.

Comment: ...and if you ignore those warnings, you get 404

Comment: This is no longer the case - "not entirely political neutral 'Taiwan, Province of China'. Now it says just 'Taiwan'"

Answer (score 59):

See code snippets :

```
String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();

for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {

    Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

    System.out.println("Country Code = " + obj.getCountry() 
        + ", Country Name = " + obj.getDisplayCountry());

}
```

Refer to this [country list in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/display-a-list-of-countries-in-java/) for more examples.

Comment: Never knew this existed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Map out of this page http://www.theodora.com/country_digraphs.html
2. Save it to a file (I suggest XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder class)
3. Create a wrapping class that loads this Map from the file (I'd use a lazily initialized singleton) and allows access to the get(...) methods.
4. Repeat (or use a bi-directional map) these steps for each column of the table on the afore mentioned webpage.
5. Fancy-Time: Throw in some code to wrap the entries in a Reference object (SoftReference?) so that the Map won't throw MemoryErrors

Answer (score 0):

You can use from json bellow like

1. Json parsing..

   ```
   String jsonString =JSON_DATA;
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
   try {
           JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);              

           for (JsonNode node : rootNode) {
               String countrycode = node.path("code").asText();
               String dialnumber = node.path("dial_code").asText();
               String countryname = node.path("name").asText();

           }


   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Json String here

   ```
   public static String JSON_DATA="

    [
      {
       "name": "Afghanistan",
       "dial_code": "+93",
       "code": "AF"
      }, 

     {
      "name": "Aland Islands",
     "dial_code": "+358",
     "code": "AX"
     },


   {
     "name": "Albania",
    "dial_code": "+355",
    "code": "AL"
    },

   {
    "name": "Algeria",
    "dial_code": "+213",
    "code": "DZ"
    },

   {
      "name": "AmericanSamoa",
      "dial_code": "+1684",
      "code": "AS"
     }]";
   ```
3. Or You can  download full json from link : https://gist.github.com/Goles/3196253