# How to get the list of country names in a language (english for instance)?

Tags: java, grails, localization, groovy, country-codes

Using Java, you can get the list of ISO2 codes through `Locale.getISOCountries()` (see this related question [Best way to get a list of countries in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712231/best-way-to-get-a-list-of-countries-in-java)).

However, I would like to have the **list of all country names** (in English for example) and not the list of ISO2 country codes. How can I do that by programming in Java or Groovy ?

Thank you very much,

Fabien.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Groovy, this prints a sorted list of country names:

```
def countries = [] as SortedSet

Locale.availableLocales*.displayCountry.each {
  if (it) {
    countries << it
  }
}

println countries
```

In my locale, this prints

> [Albania, Algeria, Argentina, Australia, Austria, Bahrain, ..., Yemen]

You need to use a `Set` rather than a `List` because there are multiple locales for some countries, e.g. French Canada and English Canada locales for the country Canada.