# Populate a choice menu with all countries to in java

Tags: java

I have a problem. I want to make a drop down choice menu with a list of all the countries in the world without having to add each and every country on its own. Is there a way to do this?

I am applying them in a JFrame to make a GUI.

Comment: Well, you do need to get all the countries from somewhere... What kind of `drop down choice menu`? Are we talking about a swing-component, Android, another framework?

Comment: did you mean in ruby? yes :)

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712231/best-way-to-get-a-list-of-countries-in-java

Comment: Please clarify your question and add some code to show what you've tried so far!

Comment: Fixed it, Used an answer I got here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to develop a Swing application, then use following statement.

```
 JComboBox box=new JComboBox(getAllCountries());


 public String[] getAllCountries() {
    String[] countries = new String[Locale.getISOCountries().length];
    String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
    for (int i = 0; i < countryCodes.length; i++) {
        Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCodes[i]);
        countries[i] = obj.getDisplayCountry();
    }
    return countries;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks bro!! I have searched a lot for this.. This is the only answer that actually answers my question.. Thanks again.