# How to get a country's official name from a Java Locale?

Tags: java, iso-3166

In ISO-3166, when it comes to the country, there is a difference between "short name" and "full name".

For example, Denmark (link to iso.org reference : https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:DK).
Its country code would be DK and DNK (alpha-2 and alpha-3), its numeric code is 208, its short name is 'Denmark', and its full name is 'the Kingdom of Denmark'.

For my current project, I have all the information I need except full name.

Does anyone know of a way to get that kind of data?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712231/best-way-to-get-a-list-of-countries-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's in-built localization doesn't support official country names.

Here's [the entry for Denmark](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/57148c79bd75/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/util/resources/LocaleNames.properties#l931) in the localization data

```
DK=Denmark
```

You can use a REST API like https://restcountries.eu/, or I found [this CSV](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/57129a6a-1738-4ce2-8d40-3274c7c9cb27/fco-index-of-geographical-names) file which seems to contain what you want. You will need to parse it.

Comment: Java's Locale class (at least for Java 8) is not really up to date either. So I think it might be a good idea to use an external library. But I can't really find one that support countries' full name. Maybe I missed it, though.

Comment: @programminator I updated my answer with a few google results i found